# Tengo este error con nodemon creo

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Hola necesito ayuda ya que no encuetro solucion a esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la imagen estoy corriendo una app con node y express para un backend pero mi problema creo que es con nodemon ya que al momento de guardar un archivo se crachea la app pero si lo hago de nuevo corre como si nada y antes no hacia esto.
alguna solucion o idea a este problema?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya agregue la parte del codigo de index.js en la linea 45, deje por unos dias este codigo, y hoy que lo checo ya fuciona solo, no modifique nada y se arreglo.
pienso que el problema es con los puertos pero cuando tenian este problema los cheque.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora los vuelvo a checar y son iguales, la verdad no se cual sea el problema, espero que no me vuelva a pasar.
Si saben de algo que lo solucione se los agradesco, por el momento se areglo solo.

Comment: Ya agregue el index.js en la linea 45. Pero se soluciono solo